# Swift: Corelocation handling NSError in didFailWithError

Tags: swift, ios8, nserror, didfailwitherror

I'm using CoreLocation to successfully determine the user's location. However when i try to use the CLLocationManagerDelegate method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
```

I run into problems with the error term.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("didFailWithError \(error)")

    if let err = error {
        if err.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This results in a 'Use of unresolved identifier kCLErrorLocationUnknown' error message. I know that the kCLErrors are enums and that they have evolved in Swift but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Update for Swift 4:** The error is now passed to the callback as `error: Error` which can be cast to an `CLError`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    if let clErr = error as? CLError {
        switch clErr.code {
        case CLError.locationUnknown:
            print("location unknown")
        case CLError.denied:
            print("denied")
        default:
            print("other Core Location error")
        }
    } else {
        print("other error:", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

---

*Older answer:* The Core Location error codes are defined as

```
enum CLError : Int {
    case LocationUnknown // location is currently unknown, but CL will keep trying
    case Denied // Access to location or ranging has been denied by the user
    // ...
}
```

and to compare the enumeration value with the integer `err.code`, `toRaw()`
can be used:

```
if err.code == CLError.LocationUnknown.toRaw() { ...
```

Alternatively, you can create a `CLError` from the error code and check that
for the possible values:

```
if let clErr = CLError.fromRaw(err.code) {
    switch clErr {
    case .LocationUnknown:
        println("location unknown")
    case .Denied:
        println("denied")
    default:
        println("unknown Core Location error")
    }
} else {
    println("other error")
}
```

**UPDATE:** In Xcode 6.1 beta 2, the `fromRaw()` and `toRaw()` methods have been
replaced by an `init?(rawValue:)` initializer and a `rawValue` property, respectively:

```
if err.code == CLError.LocationUnknown.rawValue { ... }

if let clErr = CLError(rawValue: code) { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3 it's now:

```
if error._code == CLError.denied.rawValue { ... }
```

Comment: This is correct. Just in case, casting to NSError will probably be deprecated soon:

    `let code = (error as NSError).code; if code == CLError.denied.rawValue { ... } // CODE SMELL!!`

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.1:

```
func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    let err = CLError.Code(rawValue: (error as NSError).code)!
    switch err {
    case .locationUnknown:
        break
    default:
        print(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. I found another variant without using NSError.

Comment: which one!? :-)