# NSError code check: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two Int operands

Tags: ios, swift, nserror

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? "error" is NSError returned from CloudKit.

```
if error.code == Int(CKErrorCode.NetworkFailure) {
    //do something
}
```

Gives me this error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two Int operands

If I do this, it works fine:

```
if error.code == 4 {
    //do something
}
```

Where 4 is the actual error code.

Comment: I think it's message that's messed up. Is perhaps the error an optional?

Comment: Show more code, how is `error`, `error.code` and `CKErrorCode` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the subject covered that. "error" is just an NSError that is returned from CloudKit. NSError definition is fairly standard. I did check and neither are optionals.

Comment: Perhaps similar as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24509912/1187415.

Comment: How about comparing to CKErrorCode.NetworkFailure.rawValue ?

Comment: @nickfalk: That's what I meant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `Int` doesn't have a constructor that takes `CKErrorCode` as input.

As in the comments, the way to compare the two values would be:

```
if error.code == CKErrorCode.NetworkFailure.rawValue {
    //do something
}
```

Thankfully, the error messages have been improved for XCode 7 and Swift 2, so you would see:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(CKErrorCode)'

Which is a much better indicator of what went wrong.